# jquery not defined error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to bring banner scroll in magento2. I am using owl carousel for this purpose. Everything have done and implemented and is showing in firefox without any errors. But when checked in chrome, i found jquery not defined error. After some diggings, i found we need to use call it as "require" to trigger jquery. So i have modifed the js and still firefox is rendering everything correctly, but in chrome its still the issue.
Script currently i have

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navRewind: true,
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        loop: true
    });

});
```

I have tried different kinds, but every time chrome is giving me this error [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxODT.png)

could anybody assist me in this? Thanks.

Comment: plz display your requirejs-config.js

Comment: I have not written that js. I have just tried to call a phtml file in homepage using below
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}
that test.phtml file contain above js.

Comment: you have to defined owlCarousel js inside requirejs-config.js

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
$(document).ready(function($) {
   console.log('running');
   // your script
});});
```

Comment: This is valid answer, This is not a comment.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue and i have fix it by following solution. please try it.

**Step 1:**
Please open owl.carousel.js file and add below code at the top of actual jquery(owl.carousel.js) script

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function () {
```

and now add the end bracket at the end of the jquery(`owl.carousel.js`) file.

```
});
```

its done for `owl.carousel.js`...

**Step 2:**
Now please create one file at root(`Namespance_Module`) of the extensions.
Name: `requirejs-config.js`

and please add this code

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            owlcarousel: 'Namespance_Module/js/owl.carousel'
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 3:**
Now in your phtml file (template file) please write code as per below:

```
require([ 'jquery', 'owlcarousel'], function(){
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navRewind: true,
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        loop: true
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: i am not created a module. i have done a phtml file and called inside Magento_Theme template and called inside homepage page. where should i put that requirejs-config.js ?

Comment: In default Magento 2, you will get this file at below location.

[Magento_root]/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

So you can create same file in your current theme directory. Let me know if you still require my help.

Comment: still no luck. I am trying to call a phtml file in  homepage. That phtml file contain slider code. Also written requirejs config file in theme root. No luck. everytime stuck with error:http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch 
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
(function ($, window, document) {

    var Carousel = {

Comment: i referred this: http://cookie-code.net/magento-2/using-requirejs-in-magento-2-implementing-owl-slider/

Answer (score 3):

owlcarousel needs to be injected. The correct way to do so is by defining owl carousel in the `requirejs-config.js` file in your themes names root.

For example, see this:

```
var config = {

    deps: [
        "js/main",
        "js/modernizr.custom"
    ],

    map: {
        '*': {
            'stellar': 'js/jquery.stellar.min',
            'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min',
            'sticky' : 'js/jquery.sticky',
            'tether' : 'js/tether.min',
            'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap.min'
        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "stellar": ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
        "owlcarousel": ["jquery"],
        "tether": ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
    }
};
```

**Explanation**:

- `deps` is calling these files on all pages. In my `web/js/` folder in my theme I have a file calles `main.js` and `modernizr.custom.js`
- in `maps` I've defined several libraries. Just call them WITHOUT the suffix (`.js`)
- in `shim` I defined some requirements. Those plugins cant be loaded without its value (here: `jquery`, which sets the dependency on Mangeto2's jQuery Library, which is included **automatically**

**Calling the function**:

You can easily now call owl carousel by requesting it in your `define` on your `.phtml`-File:

```
 require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'owlcarousel'], function($){

   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navRewind: true,
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        loop: true
    });

});
```

Clear your cache with `php bin/magento cache:flush && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/full_page/* pub/static/*` and reload the page. Now the console should be clean.