# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error owl Carousel slider

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am trying to use slider in my magneto custom module

I did Following steps:

1 create a file `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            my: 'Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel',
        }
    }
};
```

2. created a `owl.carousle.js` fine in `web/js`

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var owl = $("#owl-demo1");
        owl.owlCarousel({
       // Most important owl features
   margin:10,       
   items : 4,
   itemsCustom : false,
   itemsDesktop : [1199,2],
   itemsDesktopSmall : [900,4],
   itemsTablet: [768,3],
   itemsTabletSmall: [700,2],
   itemsMobile : [479,1],


   singleItem : false,
   itemsScaleUp : false,


   //Basic Speeds
   slideSpeed : 200,
   paginationSpeed : 800,
   rewindSpeed : 1000,

   //Autoplay
   autoPlay : true,
   stopOnHover : false,

   // Navigation
   navigation : true,
   navigationText: ["Left","Right"],
   rewindNav : true,
   scrollPerPage : true,


   // Responsive 
   responsive: true,
   responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
   responsiveBaseWidth: window,



   //Mouse Events
   dragBeforeAnimFinish : true,
   mouseDrag : true,
   touchDrag : true,



   });
   });
   ```

The slider is not working giving an error in the console

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error

Comment: Magento way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227649/57696

Comment: is that your `owl.carousle.js` ?

Comment: @magefms Yes its `owl.carousle.js`

Comment: @bob_motor i want to include in m custom Module.. How can i do this

Comment: You have raised a good point, normally people forget to use require. +1 on your question

Comment: Please check below link: This will help you [(jQuery not define)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103395/jquery-not-defined-error-in-magento-2/148548#answer-103450)

Comment: Update your code with your folder path...it will be more helpful to investigate

Comment: @WaqarAli I showed you how to add owl carousel in custom M2 module. All you need is in the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your requirejs-config.js with the below code

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'my': 'Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel'
},
 shim: {
    'my': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
}
};
```

and then wherever you're calling this js you'd call like below

```
require(['jquery','my'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // the below must be as per your requirement

        $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            navigation : true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            loop: true,
            smartSpeed: 450
          });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i did the same but its giving me error `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/magento23s/pub/static/version1556888431/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/my.js”.`

Answer (score 1):

You need include jquery in top of your js as below

```
 require(['jquery', 'my'],function($){ 
  Your script code 
 });
```

Also edit  the require-config.js with single quotes for "my" object

```
var config = {
     map: {
        '*': {
            'my': 'Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel',
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: i included Your given code in my owl.carousle.js now i am getting a console error as `Error: Script error for: js/my
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Still same Error

Comment: Have you done static-content deploy?

Comment: yes i have done that here is a warning `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/magento23s/pub/static/version1556886980/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/my.js”.`

Comment: see my updated answer again

Answer (score 1):

Add in your requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    deps: [
    "js/my" // connect your js file
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

add your code in jquery require like this, also add your "my" in require, so that it will also check if owl is ready:

```
require([
    'jquery','my'
], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var owl = $("#owl-demo1");
        owl.owlCarousel({
            // Most important owl features
            margin:10,
            items : 4,
            itemsCustom : false,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,2],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [900,4],
            itemsTablet: [768,3],
            itemsTabletSmall: [700,2],
            itemsMobile : [479,1],


            singleItem : false,
            itemsScaleUp : false,


//Basic Speeds
            slideSpeed : 200,
            paginationSpeed : 800,
            rewindSpeed : 1000,

//Autoplay
            autoPlay : true,
            stopOnHover : false,

// Navigation
            navigation : true,
            navigationText: ["Left","Right"],
            rewindNav : true,
            scrollPerPage : true,


// Responsive 
            responsive: true,
            responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
            responsiveBaseWidth: window,



//Mouse Events
            dragBeforeAnimFinish : true,
            mouseDrag : true,
            touchDrag : true,



        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Getting error `Error: Script error for: my
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`

Comment: and here is a warning in console `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/magento23s/pub/static/version1556886980/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/my.js”.`

Comment: Have you run deployment script? because this error indicates that you need to run deployment `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and clean command after that `php bin/magento cache:clean
`

Comment: Yes i have all these already..