# How to add 3rd party js library to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, js-css, third-party-library

I am trying to install the following slider to my own Module https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html.

But unfortunately, Magento has its own complicated mechanism to manage its static assets like js and css.

My question is, "Is it possible to install 3rd party js extension on Magento 2?" if yes then how to make it work?

Comment: Call the relevant JS scripts in your module so that they load.  There is also a pre built Magento 2 module https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_OwlCarousel2

Comment: Hi yeah, I am currently reading that as well.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264940/custom-javascript-not-working/264941#264941

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273357/referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-error-owl-carousel-slider/273363#273363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise downloading the JS file from the Owl carousel website and including it in your theme. Steps for that can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264940/custom-javascript-not-working/264941#264941) as Prathap linked.

But if you really want to include external JS you can do so via layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```