# Magento2 jQuery.live is not a function on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, jquery

When i am going to place an order on checkout page then on page load i am getting an error in firebug like jQuery.live is not a function on checkout page but not display always it shows sometime.

Please check the attached screen shot :

[image]

Please suggest about this.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273357/referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-error-owl-carousel-slider/273363#273363

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264940/custom-javascript-not-working/264941#264941

Comment: Just remove minification and check for the function which causing the error, it seems like an dependency issue or function may not be right one

Comment: @Charul Tyagi did you fix this issue or find any solution? i am getting same error on checkout.

Comment: Are you using amasty onestep checkout ?

Comment: @AsharRiaz Yes fixed i searched this live function in my custom modules in one of them .live function was used that is now deprecated so i used .on instead and issue solved.